# GridLayout design style with icons and text using material design?

Tags: android, android-layout

What is the best way to achieve a design icons with text with the support library for the design material.It would look something like the image of link above
[enter link description here](http://static.ibnlive.in.com/ibnlive/pix/ibnhome/4-whatsapp-150514.jpg)

Comment: Nested `LinearLayout`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **Karakuri** said in comments, nested LinearLayouts will render your the required view like this

[image]

Here is the code for layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_repeat_48d"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Repeat"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_heart_48d"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Favourite"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_shuffle_48dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Shuffle"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The code is just a layout structure, you have to add paddings and `ImageView` width-height as you want. You have to do a little work for your desired layout. If you want two rows likewise your uploaded picture, just replicate the layout twice.

Hope it helps or drop a comment if any trouble implementing.

Cheers!